# Eigenvalue multiplicities

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the geometric and algebraic multiplicities for each eigenvalue.
    A=[image]

Okay, so after doing calculations' , I find that the eigenvalues come out to be: 2, 1, and -1.

Great! But I am wondering what should I do next? I can't find a good example of this in my textbook.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue is its multiplicity as a root of the characteristic polynomial.

Since the eigenvalues are unique, the algebraic multiplicity for each eigenvalue is one.

What does it also mean for the geometric multiplicity (since the eigenvalues are unique)?

The geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue never exceeds its algebraic multiplicity.

What eigenspace is spanned by the eigenvalue when solving $[A− \lambda I]v_i=0$? That is, the geometric multiplicity is the dimension of the nullspace of $A– \lambda I$.

Said differently, how many linearly independent eigenvectors can you find for each eigenvalue?

In this problem, the geometric multiplicity for each eigenvalue is one.

See [*Multiplicities*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Algebraic_multiplicities), go through the $4x4$ matrix example there which has two repeated eigenvalues.

Comment: The algebraic multiplicies are one for each of the eigenvalues?

Comment: It must mean that the geometric multiplicies are also one, since they cannot exceed the algebraic ones.

Comment: I am still a bit confused on Geometric multplicies, it is the number of feature vectors in the eigenvector?